# Interface Builder in Xcode 4. How to generate class files?

Tags: cocoa, xcode4, uikit, interface-builder

Okay, I haven't used Interface Builder since Xcode 3.x but I remember there being a menu item that would automagically regenerate the class file with IBActions/IBOutlets for any object created in IB. I can't seem to find that in the Xcode 4 version. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate IBAction directly from interface builder storyboard view :  you have to open the interface nib file and then you have to open assistant mode, now in the right pane you will find the .m implementation , now you can control drag from a component ( eg a button) to the code pane , here a popup will appear and confirming the dialog, Xcode will generate the related code ...

Before you have to create a class(view controller) file and link it to the nib file .

Xcode 4 is really different from Xcode3 and the workflow is completely different , so take a look at the new assistant view, that is one of the most innovation, you will find new kind of automations to speedup the development process .